# Three.js won't render when object is rotated

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js, render, mesh

Arrggh, I really need some help, going nuts. I have a three.js HTML5 page with three objects (1)cube, (2)cylinder and (3) an imported OBJ mesh.

Everything works fine until I try to rotate the mesh (guitar), then nothing renders. I can rotate and position it fine before adding to the scene, but if I try to rotate it within the render function everything goes black.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Code is attached below.

thanks

```
    <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/loaders/DDSLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loaders/OBJMTLLoader.js"></script>

    <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

    <script>


      var targetRotation = 0;
        var targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;

        var mouseX = 0;
        var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;

        var container, stats;

        var camera, scene, renderer;
  var guitar,button1,cube;

        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;


        init();
        animate();


        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
            camera.position.z = 640;

            // scene

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 );
            scene.add( ambient );

            var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
            directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ).normalize();
            scene.add( directionalLight );

            // model

            THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );

            var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
            loader.load( 'obj/male02/guitarOBJ.obj', 'obj/male02/male02_dds.mtl', function ( guitar ) {
    guitar.rotation.x = 1.57;
            scene.add( guitar );

            } );

            var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 5, 5, 50, 32 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} );
    button1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    button1.rotation.y = 1;
    button1.rotation.z = 0.75;
    scene.add( button1 );

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100 );

            for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i += 2 ) {

                var hex = Math.random() * 0xffffff;
                geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHex( hex );
                geometry.faces[ i + 1 ].color.setHex( hex );

            }

            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, overdraw: 0.5 } );

            cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            cube.position.y = 150;
            scene.add( cube );


            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            /////////document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
          document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        ///function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            ///mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
            ///mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;

        ///}

  function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

            mouseXOnMouseDown = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
            targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;

            targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.02;

        }

        function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

            document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseOut( event ) {

            document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

        }

      function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

            if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                mouseXOnMouseDown = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;

            }

        }

        function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

            if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.05;

            }

        }
        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();

        }

        function render() {

      guitar.rotation.y = button1.rotation.y = cube.rotation.y += ( targetRotation - cube.rotation.y ) * 0.05;

    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: can you attach your guitarOBJ.obj model?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

[**Check this fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wilt/7ctL3/30/). It is done exactly like how you did it.

Maybe the if clause makes a difference? Maybe you should not try rotating something before the mesh is properly loaded?

```
if(mesh){
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;
}
```

Otherwise I would try simplifying the code to isolate the issue. Could be something else bothering you.